# iPhone stocks app bubble

Tags: iphone, charts, quartz-graphics

I am trying to draw a bubble similar to the one used in the Stocks app. However, I cannot seem to replicate the graphics. I have jagged lines although I use anti aliasing and the colors are blurred. Am I not using Quartz at its real power or I simply need to change my approach? Is there any alternative to Quartz that can deliver sharper graphics?

[image]

Comment: Post your code and a screen dump of what it does. Then someone should be able to help better.

Comment: This is more like a conceptual question, I'm interested in the methods that can be used to achieve this result, not the specific code.